# printing size_t: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int'

Tags: c, gcc, printf

I try to print size_t by casting to unsigned long (as suggested in the book "C programming a modern approach) like the following:

```
printf("size:%lu, bsize:%lu", (unsigned long)size, (unsigned long)bsize);
printf("size:%lu, bsize:%lu", ((unsigned long)size), ((unsigned long)bsize));
```

The first line would give me warning (gcc):

`warning: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'size_t' [-Wformat]`

What's the difference between the first line and the second line? All I did was putting extra parenthesis, what exactly does that do?

I know I can use "%z" but this problem bugs me.

Comment: Your error message does not relate to your example, check your example program.

Comment: Why don't you cast it in `int` ? Or you could use the `%zu` format. Casts should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: On a 32bit OS `size_t` most likely is an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Works fine: http://ideone.com/JBszdh

Comment: ok maybe I do have some macro which mess it up let me check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are no ugly `#define`s around

```
printf("size:%lu, bsize:%lu", (unsigned long)size, (unsigned long)bsize);
```

and

```
printf("size:%lu, bsize:%lu", ((unsigned long)size), ((unsigned long)bsize));
```

are equivalent.

And therefore they shall result in the same code/warnings/errors.

If they don't, there is something broken.

Comment: OK maybe it is some silly macro I haven't figure it out yet, but a simple example work just fine. Thanks.